# Missing command in main.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a specific command that is guild only in my main.py and have 2 cogs currently, but when i go to run the bot the command doesnt show up, nor says it has been synced. I even tried switching the guild it was for and made a another command that was global and yet it still did not show, so im confused as to what im doing wrong.

main.py code
[code](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/azaporewiq)

Comment: Post your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are using `synced = await client.tree.sync()`. Note that you are not specifying a `guild`, which makes your bot only sync global commands.

If you want to synchronize commands that are registered in a guild, specify the guild parameter:

```py
guild = client.get_guild(YOUR_GUILD_ID)
#  if you don't have guild's cache
#  you can use discord.Object(id=YOUR_GUILD_ID)

synced = await client.tree.sync(guild=guild)
```